# Disable group site's Title click behaviour

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, title

it seems that the default functionality of a group site's title when clicked is to open the profile card of this group. Is there a way to change it to navigate to the site's home page - or any other url for that matter?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you cannot customize the behavior of clicking the title of a team site with an out-of-box option.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seemed to be the case, however i was hoping that maybe someone knew something on this. I remember reading something about this being in the roadmap, but i may have been mistaken.